# WooCommerce - get quantity for variation price filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to get the quantity inside the woocommerce hooks for changing the variation price? I can seem to see where the AJAX call passes in the quantity selected, I want to perform something like the below.

Maybe its not possible to read server side?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'my_variation', 10, 3);

function my_variation( $data, $product, $variation ) {
   $qty = _POST['qty'] ??;
    $data['price_html'] = $qty * $product->sale_price
}
```

Comment: No it's not… The chosen quantity is a live event on client side.

Comment: It is not possible on server site.